# Copying Timesheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following VBA for a button to create a new 4 weekly timesheet, clearing the appropriate data and changing the new.

I am struggling to get the carry over of leave from the current sheet, Cell I42 to the new sheet I39. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks

```
Sub NewTimesheet()
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa:

    Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    wsToCopy.Cells.Copy wsNew.Cells

    wsNew.Range("C7:H13").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("C15:H21").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("C23:H29").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("C31:H37").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("K7:M13").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("K15:M21").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("K23:M29").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("K31:M37").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("J42").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("A7").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A37").Value + 1
    wsNew.Range("I39").ClearContents
    wsNew.Range("J39").ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A7").Text
    ActiveSheet.Range("I43").Copy wsNew.Range("I39").Value


    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just copy the active sheet rather than add a new sheet and copy to it? I guess your code doesn't work because the active sheet is the new sheet added (`wsNew`). Use the variables you have sensibly set up. Also, don't use `Value` in your copy line.

Comment: To elaborate, eg in this line `wsNew.Range("A7").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A37").Value + 1`, `wsNew` and `ActiveSheet` are the same.

Comment: Firstly, you already set your two sheet objects. Why are you still using `ActiveSheet` in your code? Replace `ActiveSheet` with whatever sheet you are wanting it to represent, whether it be `wsToCopy` or `wsNew`.

Answer (score 1):

Think you can shorten your code a little. By the way, I don't think it's a very good idea to base your code on the active sheet in case it's run when a different sheet is unintentionally active.

```
Sub NewTimesheet()

    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa:

    Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    wsToCopy.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set wsNew = ActiveSheet

    With wsNew
        .Range("C7:H13,C15:H21,C23:H29,C31:H37,K7:M13,K15:M21,K23:M29,K31:M37,J42").ClearContents
        .Range("A7").Value = wsToCopy.Range("A37").Value + 1
        .Range("I39:J39").ClearContents
        .Name = wsToCopy.Range("A7").Text 'not sure which sheet this should be
        .Range("I39").Value = wsToCopy.Range("I43").Value
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, since you already set your two sheets with `wsToCopy` and `wsNew`, why would you still need to use `ActiveSheet`?

Nevertheless, this appears to work for me.

```
Sub NewTimesheet()
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa:

    Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    wsToCopy.Cells.Copy wsNew.Cells

    With wsNew
        .Range("C7:H13").ClearContents
        .Range("C15:H21").ClearContents
        .Range("C23:H29").ClearContents
        .Range("C31:H37").ClearContents
        .Range("K7:M13").ClearContents
        .Range("K15:M21").ClearContents
        .Range("K23:M29").ClearContents
        .Range("K31:M37").ClearContents
        .Range("J42").ClearContents
        .Range("A7").Value = wsToCopy.Range("A37").Value + 1
        .Range("I39").ClearContents
        .Range("J39").ClearContents
        .Name = .Range("A7").Text
        wsToCopy.Range("I43").Copy .Range("I39")
    End With


    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```